# Delayed loading of tailwind styles in NextJ s (version 13.0.4) application

Tags: tailwind-css, vercel, next.js13

The tailwind styles are being applied after a delay after the initial load of the next js app.
I have some custom classes in the globals.css and custom colors and borders in the tailwind.config.

Here is my globals.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.hidden_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.fit_max_parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.fit_max_child {
  width: 95%;
  height: 90%;
  max-width: 90rem;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .fit_max_child {
    height: 95%;
  }
}

.custom_scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.custom_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background-color: var(--bg-primary);
}

.custom_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--accent);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .custom_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
  }
}
```

Here is my tailwind.config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "!./node_modules",
  ],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: "660px",

      md: "840px",

      lg: "1024px",

      xl: "1280px",

      "2xl": "1536px",
    },
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
};
```

I saw some issues opened on github on similar questions and they all had same answer which was to downgrade, but downgrading breaks a lot of other things as well, I'd appreciate if there's a solution for the current situation.
To get an idea of how this delay looks on the production build down below is an example video
[Video link](https://youtu.be/TWzzWI1FVVM)

Note: A lot of components on the page are client components. (I don't think that should cause some problems but just to let you know.)

**What I have tried**
I have tried downgrading to previous next js versions but they end up breaking some things here and there and on top of that don't quite provide the solution.

**What I expect**
The best case scenario would be the html loads with the correct styles, and the unstylised version isn't shown. If there's a workaround for this I'm down for those too because currently the no style skeleton load looks quite bad.

Thank you for your time